# Laravel adding factory own random reference

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `categories` table which has a `parent_id` attribute which should point to a parent category. Top level categories will have their `parent_id` set to `null`.

Is it possible to seed the database through a factory so that one part are the parent categories, while the others are randomly pointed to parent categories?

Factory:

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
    ];
});
```

Seeder (not working):

```
factory(Category::class, 50)->create();

factory(Category::class, 450)->create(
    ['parent_id' => Category::all()->pluck('id')->random()]
);
```

Seeder here picks only one random element, and all subsequent child categories have (for example) reference to category ID 15.

I know how to manually create it through seeders without using factories, but I would like to do it like this, if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your functionality using Seeder states as shown here.

```
$factory->define(Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'parent_id' => Category::inRandomOrder()->take(1)->first()->id,
    ];
});

$factory->state(Category::class, 'withParent', function (Faker\Generator $faker){
    return [
        'parent_id' => Category::inRandomOrder()->take(1)->first()->id,
    ];
});
```

Optimized the category random, to not fetch all every time. Not 100% certain that is the right call procedure, but you should get the idea.

When you call the parent the syntax is.

```
factory(Category::class, 5)->create();
```

If you want categories with parents, you can apply the state and it is added to the seeding.

```
factory(Category::class, 5)->states('withParent')->create();
```

Comment: Sure, but defining it like that disables me to create parent categories? How will I produce first 50 parent categories which have `null` for parent?

Comment: Updated my answer using factory states